# Defining variables in Ruby if undefined (not ||=)

Tags: ruby

We know that you can define variables in Ruby using

```
x || = 1 # 1
x || = 2 # still 1
```

This also works

```
a = 1 unless defined? b
# a is 1 now
```

But this doesn't

```
a = 1 unless defined? a
# a is nil here
```

Can anybody see why this should make sense? I think that `a = 1 unless defined? a` sounds better than `a ||= 1`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Usually, for most code, it doesn't make sense to check if a local variable is defined, because you can just look at the code above or at that point and see if there is a line that defines the variable (`a = ..`).  It makes more sense to use `defined?` on instance variables, global variables, and constants.

Comment: This is for some script that we want to ```require``` insider another. Because a variable may be already defined in the second script, we don't want to override it.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, that won't work.  A local variable defined at the top level of a Ruby file is not visible in other files.  The scope of that variable is the file where it was defined.  I just tested this in Ruby 2.2.0.  You could use instance variables or global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `unless` clause doesn't have its own scope so `a` **is actually defined** in the scope containing the `unless` clause.

Try this:

```
def foo
    unless true
        a = 1
    end
    a
end

foo
=> nil


def bar
    a
end

bar
=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (or want) the `defined?` for this.

```
a = 1 unless a
```

works for me in Ruby 2.2, haven't tested it with other versions but I would expect it to work on them as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @pjs suggested,

```
a = 1 unless a
```

seems to work good (as long as the variable in question isn't supposed to be boolean--or nil--). Honestly, I understand that `a ||= 1` is sort of canonic, but sounds pretty weird to me.

Also, I discovered that

```
A = 1 unless defined? A
```

works too. Maybe constants have a different behavior during compilation/interpretation.